# Generating Token using Identity

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am developing a Web API application using Asp.Net Identity. At first we will have to generate token by sending this: `grant_type=password&username=email&password=pwd` and the following code:

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenExpiryTimeInHours"])),
            // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
```

Now my question is: Suppose a user is registered from the facebook and now the password is saved in the AspnetUsers table. How we can generate the token for that user in my scenario? I didn't find a way to get the password in identity.

Help me on this..

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you want users to login to your site using their fb account and you want to save their credentials in AspNetUsers? That is not how it should work. You'll need to register your app in fb. When a user logs in, this is done on fb. fb will authenticate the user and reroute to the ExternalLogin handler in your account controller. Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on#creating-the-app-in-facebook-and-connecting-the-app-to-the-project